Как создать сниппет в QtCreator
В QtCreator есть возможность сгенерировать код, например для switch. Это выглядит следующим образом: пусть есть enum, например:
enum E
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
};

Теперь, если написать:
E e;
switch (e)
{

}

То QtCreator подсветит на этой строчке warning (примерно такой: Enumeration values: A, B, C not handled in switch) и появится предложение по исправлению, применив которое будет сгенерирован код:
switch (e)
{
case A:
case B:
case C:
    break;
}

Я бы хотел иметь такую же возможность для генерации визитеров по типу variant, который они обрабатывают, но из коробки такой возможности не нашел. К сожалению возможности макросов мне не помогли (либо я что то не так сделал). Как можно добавить такую возможность? Возможно есть какие то плагины или инструменты по созданию сниппетов в QtCreator.

это случайно не то что вы ищите?

@DeniskaSosiSka Не совсем, в моем варианте нужно выявить тип переменной, для которой создается visitor, из типа variant'а достать типы, которые в нем перечислены и для каждого типа создать шаблон реализации функции.
